# How can i add multi web part which used angularjs module?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

### How can i add multi web part sharepoint which used angularjs module?

I have web part in which i have used angular the problem is when i want to add this web part for several times in a page i don't know how to separate angular modules name? when there is only one web part added in the page it works properly but when there are more than one problem start

i guess i should create dynamic names for modules in server side am i right? is there any other way?

I used angular.bootstrap.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: i add modules dynamically to the page and the end of the page after page loading i add modules to the angular.bootstrap.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me! Do you happen to have an example of doing this?  Could you post it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

This [resource](https://ofstack.com/javascript/35631/angularjs-users.angular.-bootstrap-to-complete-manual-loading-of-modules.html) helped me to figure out how to load different angularjs html+js files in 2 different content editor webparts. I also made sure to load angularjs only once on the page.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.